# Testing HLS using JMeter

Tags: java, regex, jmeter, http-live-streaming

I am using JMeter to test HLS playback from a Streaming Server. So, the first HTTP request is for a master manifest file(m3u8). Say,

```
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/file1.m3u8
```

The reply to this will result in a playlist something like,

```
subsubFolder/360p/file1.m3u8
subsubFolder/480p/file1.m3u8
subsubFolder/720p/file1.m3u8
```

So, next set of URLs become

```
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/file1.m3u8
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/480p/file1.m3u8
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/720p/file1.m3u8
```

Now, individual reply to these further will be an index of chunks, like

```
0/file1.ts
1/file1.ts
2/file2.ts
3/file3.ts
```

Again, we have next set of URLs as

```
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/0/file1.ts
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/1/file1.ts
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/2/file1.ts
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/3/file1.ts
```

This is just the case of one set(360p). There will be 2 more sets like these(for 480p, 720p).

I hope the requirement statement is clear uptill this.
**Now, the problem statement.**

Using `http://myserver/application1` as static part, regex(.+?).m3u8 is applied at 1st reply which gives `subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/file1`. This, is then added to the static part again, to get `http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/file1 + .m3u8`
The problem comes at the next stage. As, you can see, with parts extracted previously, all I'm getting is

```
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/file1/0/file1.ts
```

The problem is obvious, an extra file1, **360p/file1** in place of **360p/0**.

Any suggestions, inputs or alternate approaches appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, all you need is the file name as the other URLs can be constructed with it. Rather than using `http://myserver/application1` as static part of your regex, I would try to get the filename directly:

```
([^\/.]+)\.m3u8$
# match one or more characters that are not a forward slash or a period
# followed by a period
# followed by the file extension (m3u8)
# anchor the whole match to the end
```

Now consider your urls, e.g. `http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/file1.m3u8`, the above regex will capture `file1`, see a [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hC3mX8/1) here. Now you can construct the other URLs, e.g. (pseudo code):

```
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/ + filename + .m3u8
http://myserver/application1/subpath1/subsubFolder/360p/ + filename + /0/ + filename + .ts
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: No, only file name is not sufficient, as the **subpath** or **subsubFolder** section might/will also change. The problem is with incrementally appending the path obtained from replies obtained out of each request. I don't want to create them manually, as the number is not fixed.

Comment: Can you give a more "realistic" example of the file paths then?

Comment: Consider a structure of movies on your drive. First level might be a categorization on languages. Second might be genre. So you will have URLs
``language1/genre1
language2/genre1
language3/genre1``
This is not a web-application where you have fixed application paths. This is in respect for a media-server, where the path represents an actual mapped path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use:

- `(.*?)` - as Regular Expression (change plus to asterisk in your regex)
- `-1` - as Match No.
- `$1$`-  as template

[image: Regex 4 HLS]

See [How to Load Test HTTP Live Media Streaming (HLS) with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter) article for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to pay for a commercial plugin, then there is an easy and much more realistic solution which is a plugin for Apache JMeter provided by UbikLoadPack:

Besides doing this job for you, it will simulate the way a player would read the file. It will also scale much better than any custom script or player solution.
It supports VOD and Live which are quite difficult to script.

See:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easy-and-realistic-load-testing-of-http-live-streaming-hls-with-apache-jmeter/
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-http-live-streaming-plugin-jmeter-videostreaming-mpegdash/

Disclaimer, we are the providers of this solution